# Daylight savings time with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, dst

Quick question:

I have an issue with daylight savings time affecting the output of data on my website.

Everything is showing as being a hour ahead (we are currently in the middle of BST).

How do I make my database recognise when it's DST and output accordingly?

Programming language is PHP
Database is MySQL
The data in question is formatted as a DATETIME

And my code is:

```
<?php
echo date('D, jS F @ g:ia', strtotime($event_date));
?>
```

Comment: Store everything in UTC and display it in local timezone

Comment: @Anigel I'm not quite sue what you mean when you say "store it in UTC". As far as I'm aware MySQL settings are set to UTC. Do you mean I have to add an extra line to my .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You say to make teh database recognise when it is BST and yet you are formatting the date in php. In MySQL store everything in UTC then use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php to set the corect timezone before using date() in php to format your date

Answer (score 0):

use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` (you might want to take a look at the [php manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also store a timestamp, then use date($myFormat,$myTimeStamp);